# How to handle a Rails redirect that starts with "x" pattern in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I am new to Ruby and Rails. So far I've successfully:

- updated a url from `/dashboard` to `/specific_dashboard`
- gotten the redirect working for when you put in `/dashboard`, it now takes you to `/specific_dashboard`

The problem I am running into is redirecting when there are additional params in the url like `/dashboard/program...` or `/dashboard/dashboard_page...`

Is there Ruby syntax that would be equivalent to using a wild card like `get "/dashboard/*" => redirect("/specific_dashboard")`. I've tried this and `match '/*dashboard' => redirect("/specific_dashboard"), via: :all` and can't get it to work. If its helpful, I have this code in my `routes.rb` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the following in **routes.rb**:

`get 'dashboard/*section', to: '<controllerName>#<actionName>'`

Here:

- controllerName = Controller Name, e.g. Home
- actionName = Action Name, e.g. Dashboard

```rb
class HomeController
  def dashboard
    # inside params[:section] you'll get 'dashboard_page'
    # if you're accessing '/dashboard/dashboard_page'
  end
end
```

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing `get 'dashboard/*section' => redirect('/specific_dashboard')` and it appears to be working. If this is against convention please let me know!

Comment: @brittanynm, glad that you managed to fix. It's not against convention. Happy coding!

Comment: *against convention or has any side effects I'm not seeing right away

Answer (score 1):

you can use nested routes.
Example you have authors and books.

```
  resources :authors do
    resources :books
  end
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources